# css dilemma(large backgrounds)

Tags: css, css-position

I'm using a large background in `<body>` tag and I want to make a container div with a width of 960px.
I want the container div to be positioned 15px down from the top, I guess i have to use position:absolute. 
My dilemma is;  the rest of the div's inside the container have to contain the same position or i could continue this like an normal 960px wide website?
Sorry for my bad english. 
Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

This should give your container a 960px width and center it with a 10px top (and bottom!) margin.

```
#container {
    width: 960 px; /* set width for container */
    margin: 10px auto; /* 10px top and bottom, center screen */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You **don't have to** use absolute positioning. A simple

```
body {margin: 0; padding: 0}
#container {width: 960px; margin: 15px 0 0;} /* or margin: 15px auto 0 */ if you want it centered
```

will do :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `position:absolute;` what that does is puts a div in a specific place on the page irrleevant of broswer window size which isn't what you want in this instance,

What you need is simply a `margin-top:$$px;`

If you are using an `id` use the `#` identifier:

```
#container {
margin-top:15px;
width:960px;
}
```

If you are using a `class` use the `.` identifier:

```
.container {
margin-top:15px;
width:960px;
{
```

All `div`s within this tag can be written and position as they normally would, no extra `padding` or `margin`s necessary.